# How to format file in Visual Studio Code (hotkeys)?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, hotkeys

How to format file | project folder | all project files (using hot keys AND using menu) in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're on Windows use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to make your code "pretty".

(This is similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> in Visual Studio)

You will have to do this for each individual file though.  I don't know of a way to format all files at once.

Comment: I'm not on Windows but `Shift` + `Alt` + `F` works for me.

Comment: Cool.  You can find the hotkey by searching (`Shift`+`Ctrl`+`P`) for "Format Document".  I'm on Windows so that's what I can speak to.  What are you running @Sergii?

Comment: macOS `Sierra`.

Comment: Good to know.  For some reason I thought a mac keyboard didn't have an `alt` key.

Answer (score 3):

Try with this hotkeys

```
Ctrl + Shift + i
```

Comment: I have everything default. Should I customize something? (...it does not work)

Comment: Try install editorconfig extension and try again  Ctrl+Shift+I

Comment: How to install it?

Comment: If you know how to, I need more details please... (I've installed but it doesn't work, may be I've installed something else or incorrectly....)

Comment: Look at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings and in File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcut in Format Document look at what is the keybinding

Answer (score 1):

@Sergii

Your question looks like you are looking for a way to format your entire code in VSCode.  If this is the case, a VSCode extension like Prettier should meet the three requirements you've listed (file | project folder | all project files).  Bear in mind though that formatting all project files is a bit unclear and you probably want to be specific about formatting all *.ts or all *.js files etc.

The below may be of help to you:

- Read about [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) because it provides ability to format entire code base
- Install [prettier-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) extension to your VSCode and enable settings that you want
- Alternatively, you can use prettier from the CLI, npm build script or via its API in build task - the choice is yours.

The one I found most useful is adding it as a git [pre-commit](https://medium.com/@brindelle/format-your-javascript-with-prettier-before-committing-177079ec356a) hook for staged files.

I hope above points you in the right direction.

SOJ

Answer (score 1):

**In case you are not able to format your code with any of these commands it's maybe because you did not set up your formatter configuration**

I recommend you to use Prettier (install from Extensions)

1. open the command palette (**CTRL + SHIFT + P** -  on windows)
2. search for `prettier: Create Configuration File`
3. hit Enter and choose your project directory folder path
4. if you can see a **.prettierc** file added into your directory, you must be able to use **SHIFT + ALT + F** to format your code

+1. also you are able to set your environment to automatically format your file at save.
You can do it writing this line in settings.json:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

Hint: Access it using the command palette again and writing settings.json, and select 
 `Preference: Open Settings (JSON)`